# JNI wierd error only on Samsung A6+ tablet

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I created an app using the JNI. At one point I need to create a Kotlin object from the C++ world, it works perfectly with the Samsung S7 and my other test phones, but an error is sometimes thrown when I am running the code on a Samsung A6+ Tablet.

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible and run it directly after loading the static library to find out where the error comes from.

```
//Result class :
package lib.up.com.library.calibration

class CalibrationResult(val0 : Float, val1 : Float, val2 : Float,
                              val3 : Float, val4 : Float, val5 : Float,
                              val6 : Float, val7 : Float, val8 : Float,
                              var shouldFlip : Boolean, var isReady : Boolean, var cadence : Int) {
    var rotationMatrix : ArrayList<Float> = arrayListOf(val0, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8)
}
```

```cpp
//Code in the native class:
jclass cls = env->FindClass("lib/up/com/library/calibration/CalibrationResult");
printf(“Found class”);
jmethodID methodId = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(FFFFFFFFFZZI)V");
printf(“Found init method”);
//Initializing with default values 
jobject obj = env->NewObject(cls, methodId,
                     0,
                     0,
                     0,
                     0,
                     0,
                     0,
                     0,
                     0,
                     0,
                     true,
                     false,
                     10);

printf(“Created result object”);
```

```
//Results in the logs :

D/PRINTS: Found class
D/PRINTS: Found init method
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: unexpected jboolean value: 140
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]     in call to NewObjectV
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]     from void lib.up.com.library.NativeClass.initCalibration(boolean)
[…]
```

Patterns :

- The unexpected jboolean value can be anything, 96, 140...
- Sometimes the JNI succeeds to create the CalibrationResult object but never more than 15 times in a row
- Out of my 4 test devices, the error appears only on the A6+ tablet
- I am creating other kotlin objects from the JNI in the app that also contain a boolean, their instantiation never crashes on all my test devices

Comment: Post your *complete* code, including the Java native declaration along with the complete C code.  One thing I note is your example code does not check *any* return values for validity.  Your `printf(“Found class”);` doesn't verify you found the class - it just verifies you made the call.  Maybe.  By using `printf()` you risk data being buffered and not emitted before the process dies abnormally.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thank you for your suggestions. You are right, I am not checking the return values, I just used the printf() to make sure the app reached a certain point.
The Native class is straightforward
public class GuNativeClass {
    public native static void initCalibration(boolean isFirst);
    […]
}

Comment: Just to rule out stack corruption (by another thread maybe?), can you use the `NewObjectA` variant with a **heap-allocated** array of values (ie a `std::vector<jvalue>`)